# To assign a range of values as 0 or 1 in an existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wanted to assign 0,1,2,3 numeric values in my existing dataframe. Following is my code:
for i in train_df['age']:

```
train_df[i].values[0:30] = 0
train_df[i].values[30:40] = 1
train_df[i].values[40:50] = 2
train_df[i].values[50:60] = 3
```

Is there any better way to assign and change the values?
(Pls note the age column contains value from 20-60 (int nos), so i want to assign  values of 20-30 as 0, 30-40 as 1 and so on)

Comment: `pd.cut` might be useful

Comment: How do i implement in the code? Do i need to define pd.cut for the list values and then assign the classified values?

Comment: there are plenty of examples on here of how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `train_df['new_age_group'] = pd.cut(train_df.age, [0,30,40, 50], include_lowest=True)`

To get numeric values like you showed you could try. For the below method please make sure you sort the age column.

```
arry = np.array([0,30,40, 50])
train_df['new_age_group'] = arry.searchsorted(train_df.age)
```

Comment: The 1st comment u posted is giving me O/P as: (30.0, 60.0]    
(-0.001, 30.0]  , I want to assign range of values in 20-30 as 0, 30-40 as 1, 40-50 as 2, 50-60 as 3

Comment: Can you try the second example please